# Reference to pointer issue?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

This is what i have:

```
void g(int *&x) {
    int a = 3;
    x = &a;
}
void h(const int *&x) {
    int b = 2;
    x = &b;
}
int main() {
    int *p = new int;
    *p = 5;
    g(p);
    cout << p << " " << *p << endl; // Print #2
    cout << p << " " << *p << endl; // Print #3
    const int*p1 = p;
    h(p1);
    cout << p << " " << *p << endl; // Print #4
    cout << p << " " << *p << endl; // Print #5
}
```

From what i understand, `Print#2` and `Print#3` should have the same result but it isn't when i compile it. It goes for `Print#4`and`Print#5` too. Can someone help me?
Updated : This is the output looks like when i compiled it on my computer:

```
00EFF9D4 3 //1
00EFF9D4 1552276352 //2
00EFF9D4 2 //3
00EFF9D4 1552276352 //4
```

shouldn't (1) and (2) be the same ? (3) and (4) either.

Comment: In the function `g`, what is `a`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Also show us the expected and actual output.

Comment: As for function `h`, you make the pointer point to a local variable which goes out of scope and cease to exist once the function returns. Dereferencing that pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which makes the whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: Probably a typo meant to be `int a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean `int a` in `g()`.

Your function make the pointer point to *a local variable*, which after the termination of the function, will go *out of scope*.

You then dereference the pointer, which invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: The why the _Undefined Behavior_ invoked in the second _cout_, while in the first one it wasn't.

Comment: @DangNguyen...Undefined Behavior...You never know what exactly will happen! ;)